# Add extra shard to collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud, apache-zookeeper

We are currently running a solrcloud with zookeeper with 1 collection named core_data, which has 2 shards with each 1 node:

```
core data - shard 1 - node 1
          - shard 2 - node 2
```

I have installed a third solr and now want to add this as a third shard.
How do i add this as a seperate shard?
I have started the solr with the zookeeper option but it has added it as secondary node of shard 2

Answer (score 0):

To have your previous collection split in 3 shards instead of 2 you will have to use Solr Collection API.
The best way is to probably split one of you shards as documented in Solr Wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api3